# Firebase Auth reCAPTCHA loop and reCAPTCHA v3

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha, firebase-app-check

I'm running a flutter web application and using firebase with phone authentication. In a specific customer network, the users are very often being stuck into a recaptcha nightmare loop until they get an error or until they are finally able to login. Normally around 3-4 people a day are logging in from this location (all computers are connected to the same company network). Has anyone had a similar issue and was able to solve it?

One of the directions I was looking at were to try and use Recaptcha v3 that doesn't need the user interaction in order to pass the verification. However, it doesn't look like firebase_auth package (flutter, dart) is using this. Does anyone knows if it's possible to set firebase_auth package to use Recaptcha V3 ?

Since AppCheck can be configured with Recaptcha V3, do you know if it's possible to integrate AppCheck into my app and use it instead of Firebase Auth app verification?